# Mysql Query to Separate space delimited String Convert into 2 columns

Tags: mysql

Space Separated Sample String: 24 4 36 2 63 5 56 7

```
MySQL Query Expected output:

    Col A  Col B
    24      4 
    36      2
    63      5
    56      7
```

Comment: Easier to do by program language

Comment: hmmm, but i need mysql query only

Comment: Procedure only. I think it's impossible by single query to return some records from one string

Comment: Use MS Excel to convert your data into `insert` query

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow :-)
Please look at [ask]
and [mcve]. This will help to get useful answers.

Comment: @prat - do you use MySQL or MariaDB ?

Comment: @BerndBuffen Mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a query that satisfies your requirements. Note that it doesn't actually select any rows from the COLUMNS table, this is necessary as MySQL does not have a row generator available, any table can go here but it must have more rows than the query below should return, otherwise it will act like a LIMIT command.

```
SET @VInput := '24 4 36 2 63 5 56 7';
SET @VRow := 0;

SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@VInput, ' ', (@VRow := @VRow + 1) * 2 - 1), ' ', -1), SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@VInput, ' ', (@VRow) * 2), ' ', -1) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.`COLUMNS` WHERE @VRow * 2 < CHAR_LENGTH(@VInput) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(@VInput, ' ', ''));
```

Let me know if you have any questions,

Regards,

James

Comment: Ohh Nice Man It Worked for  me Thank you so Much.. one doubt  i didn't got the concept of vrow can u please explain

Comment: Its a session variable (hence the @), the value in these can be changed during query runtime and so is used to count what row the query is building as execution progresses.

Comment: thanks @James Scott how Can i make this set query and select query into single query..? i tried with union but it's not working for me :(

Comment: Hi, the SET are always separate, if this has to be called in a single pass then you would need to convert the code above into a procedure that accepted the arguments VInput and VRow and then ran the SET and SELECT statements.

Comment: any other way to make above functionality in single query ?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, do you need a hand coding up the procedure? What is stopping you from using this approach? It will return a result set just like a set and can be called just as easily as a select from code. Do you need to do a join at the same time?

Comment: i have tool which takes only single query, SET and SELECT it consider different Queries and of course this are different Queries anyway .. it's ok i made single query i will upload soon Thanks ..