# SET and Select Query combine Run in a Single MySql Query to pass result in pentaho

Tags: mysql, pentaho

Below 3 queries i want to run as single query in mysql  and i will pass this result to Pentaho query component to plot some graph.

```
SET @input = select "22:4,33:4" from dual;  
SET @count := 0;     
select SUBSTRING_INDEX(@input, ' ', (@count) * 2), ' ', -1) as xyz, som_cnt as count from abc;
```

Sample string is of unknown length (22:4,33:4,96:6....)

```
expected output 

xyz      count
---------------- 
22        4
33        4
96        6
```

reference - [Mysql Query to Separate space delimited String Convert into 2 columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38177945/mysql-query-to-separate-space-delimited-string-convert-into-2-columns)

- Set query count=0, If i can Merge this SET query in select query that is also ok.
- Select query doing some parsing on input string using count - just sample substring is added. (parsing logic is added here)

I want same functionality in mysql  link shown below 
i tried this solution but i am not sure is set_config works in mysql.
[SET and SELECT within a single query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45358519/set-and-select-within-a-single-query)

or any method to run store procedure in Query component of Pentaho.

Comment: Please give sample data and expected output. Question is bit unclear. You most likely need to use Derived table (defining the session variables) , and you can then do `cross join`

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I have updated my question and expected output, if you know better solution to perform this task in single query, always welcome :)

Comment: Is this value `"22:4,33:4"` coming from some table, or is it your input ?

Comment: yes from some column of my table, but that string is not issue for me , i can pass column name in my select query , setting @count =0 in select query is issue for me

Comment: Try this: 
`select SUBSTRING_INDEX(@input, ' ', (@count) * 2), ' ', -1) as xyz, som_cnt as count from abc cross join (select @count := 0) AS user_init`

Comment: Not working gives error at cross join. can you please take query from 1st reference link i provided ion question and try with cross join, i am  also trying same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182255/discussion-between-madhur-bhaiya-and-prat).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the initialization of user-defined session variables to a Derived table, and `Cross Join` with your other table(s):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(@input, ' ', (@count) * 2), ' ', -1) AS xyz, 
       som_cnt AS `count` 
FROM abc
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @count := 0, 
                   @input := '22:4,33:4'
           ) AS user_init_vars
```