# Mysql Parsing logic on Multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql, pentaho

I have parsing Queries with below references

link1 - [SET and Select Query combine Run in a Single MySql Query to pass result in pentaho](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52924507/set-and-select-query-combine-run-in-a-single-mysql-query-to-pass-result-in-penta)
link2

Input will be shown in below Col1 showing ,In @input in the above reference link i am considering only 1 records and applying parsing logic for each cell , but issue is with **multiple rows (n rows)** and combining result with parsing logic.

```
Col1  
--------------
22:4,33:4
33:6,89:7,69:2,63:2
78:6
blank record
22:6,63:1
```

I want to create **single Query** for same as in reference link i asked for.

```
Expected Output 

 xyz   count
 ------------
 22    10
 33    10
 89    7
 69    2
 63    3
 78    6
```

I tried solutions Passing values with this conditions

- where condition pass 1 by 1 col1 in (my query)
- MAX (col1)
- group_concat

but i am not getting expected output to fit this all things in a single query.

Comment: Show a sql query that does not work.

Comment: @input = (select Col1 from table where Col1 in (Select Col1 from table limit 20)) i am using like this in link1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found solution for my question. and group_concat worked for this

```
@input= (select group_concat(Col1) from (select Col1 from table limit 10)s);
```

group_concat will merge all the rows of Col1 into comma seperated string

```
22:4,33:4,33:6,89:7,69:2,63:2,78:6,blank record,22:6,63:1
```

as we have now single string we can apply same logic as shown in link 1
we can replace blank record with REPLACE command and neglect it.

Output after using logic from link1 result

```
 xyz   count
 ------------
 22    4
 33    4
 33    6
 89    7
 69    2
 63    2
 78    6
 22    6
 63    1
```

Just use Group by

```
select xyz,sum(count) from (select link1 output)s group by xyz;
```

will give you  Final Output

```
 xyz   count
 ------------
 22    10
 33    10
 89    7
 69    2
 63    3
 78    6
```